# PHP csv function fputcsv

Tags: php

I am telling you this function "fputcsv" is buggy ! 
Why am i saying this ? 
I created a csv file with say 4 lines

```
l1data1;l1data2;l1data3;l1data4
l2data1;l2data2;l2data3;l2data4
l3data1;l3data2;l3data3;l3data4
l4data1;l4data2;l4data3;l4data4
```

ok now i simple copy this file into another file using fgetcsv and fputcsv like the following :

```
$handle = fopen($nameFile, "r") or die("Cannot open file:  ".$nameFile);
$temporaryFile = fopen($nameTempFile, "w") or die("Cannot open file:  ".$nameTempFile);
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,"", ";")) !== false) {
    fputcsv($temporaryFile, $data,";");
}
fclose($temporaryFile);
fclose($handle);
```

output file :

```
l1data1;l1data2;l1data3;l1data4
l2data1;l2data2;"l2data3";l2data4
l3data1;l3data2;"l3data3";l3data4
l4data1;l4data2;"l4data3";l4data4
```

for some reason it is leaving double quotes in my third column for no obvious reason.

Now i do it with some old ways :

```
while ($data=fgets($handle)){
   fputs($temporaryFile, $data);
}
```

Output is like expected :

```
l1data1;l1data2;l1data3;l1data4
l2data1;l2data2;l2data3;l2data4
l3data1;l3data2;l3data3;l3data4
l4data1;l4data2;l4data3;l4data4
```

Explain this !

EDIT :

```
CodeOffreArtemis;CodeOffre42C;CodeOffreSagic;ServiceType;Rate;TypeInterface;Techno;Libelles;CodeOffreCristal
G8R1_ACAB;ABE;;ACA;18;Eth;A;ACo Max2;test
G8R1_ACAC;ABE;ACABUS;ACA;18;Eth;A;ACo 20MMax;
G8R1_ACAD;AKE;ACAD;ACA;2MMAX;Eth;A;ACo 2MMax;
G8R1_ACANBA;WAB;;ACA;18;Eth;A;DSL Access Max2 ACA Nu ligne active;X201
G8R1_ACANBC;WAB;;ACA;18;Eth;A;DSL Access Max2 ACA Nu sur pré-câblée;X201
G8R1_ACANBI;WAB;;ACA;18;Eth;A;DSL Access Max2 ACA Nu ligne inactive;X201
G8R1_ACANBPORA;QAB;;ACA;18;Eth;A;DSL Access Max2 ACA Nu avec portabilité L active;X201
G8R1_ACANBR;WAB;;ACA;18;Eth;A;DSL Access Max2 ACA Nu Nd de routage;X201
G8R1_ACANCA;WAB;ACANB;ACA;18;Eth;A;DSL Access 20MMax ACA Nu ligne active;X201
```

first line is the header rest are the data.

Comment: Double quoting values is in the standard and should not lead to any problems. It's peculiar though why it does it...

Comment: Is the first line of output file 1 missing the double-quotes, too, or is that a typo?

Comment: I can't replicate what you're getting (using PHP 5.3.24) - try using `var_dump` to output the characters you're reading from the file, maybe?

Comment: no it is not a typo, the first line is fine; it's actually what is expected , it's the rest that are causing the problem.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your issue. I copy/pasted your input and your code into local files and the output is as you expect. Is this your *real* data and *real* code?

Comment: @ andrewsi the output array is fine, it's when i try to write it with fputcsv that every thing gets messed up.

Comment: is there anyway that i can attach the csv file in question ?

Comment: @user2515601 - that's my point. I've cut and pasted your code and your input file, and it's generating the data that it should be - no quotes around any of the fields. So I'm assuming that your input isn't want you're expecting.

Comment: @user2515601 - you can probably get away with just cutting and pasting a couple of lines of your input into the question.

Comment: @andrewsi can i just send you my csv somehow ?

Comment: @andrewsi  iwant to include it in here ? but how can i upload it ?

Comment: @user2515601 - just Edit your question, and paste a couple of lines in. If you can include one line that works as you expect, and one that doesn't, that would be ideal.

Comment: @user2515601 - thank you. I've just tested the code, and I can't see anything obviously wrong with the output. It's putting fields in quotes where there are spaces included in the data.

Comment: @andrewsi thank you very much !!!!! but why would it put quotes when spaces are found ?

Comment: @user2515601 - there's no one standard CSV format, so the quoting there isn't required; but it makes it easier to parse if fields with spaces are quoted. I tend to write CSVs with quotes around every field, whether they're needed or not, for consistency, but clearly `fputcsv` is fussier than I am.

Comment: See the source: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/file.c#1867

Comment: @Anthony Sterling thank you, it's sad that you get voted down for actually pointing out a real issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgetcsv($handle,"", ";");
```

Looking here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = ',' [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = '\\' ]]]] )
```

About that Length parameter:

*Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters). It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.0.4 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower.*

I can't tell for sure but it looks from the code like you're just omitting the handle which, depending on version may be legal, but seems like it could be ambiguous also? Try adding a 0 parameter there perhaps?

Comment: i had it on 1000 , and i still got the same result

Comment: OK, the parameters aren't making sense to me though.  is "" supposed to be your length parameter?  Or is it the delimiter and ";" the enclosure?  It just looks like the wrong order.  I'm wondering if this is causing some weird behavior because of the way it's being interpreted.
Also, what version of php and OS are you using? There's a magic_quotes_runtime variable in pre 5.4.x that can affect fputcsv(), even using quote characters for escaping depending on congfiguration.   Doubtful that's the issue, but if nothing else works...

Comment: Andrewsi gave me all the information i need, it's that fputcsv it's flawed, Whenever you have space it will automatically add double quotes. It shouldn't.

Comment: I wonder if this is worth submitting a bug report at http://bugs.php.net if there isn't one already?